# Transfer Information from one sheet to another sheet within a workbook Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I am looking for a formula that will transfer information from one sheet to another in a workbook.  Example: if I input a "n" in column c I need the information from column a input into column a on a separate sheet.  This information would ONLY transfer over if there is a "N" or "R" placed in column c on the first sheet.

Comment: For single cells, you could use something like `=IF(OR(COUNTIF(Sheet1!C:C,"R")>0,COUNTIF(Sheet1!C:C,"N")>0),Sheet1!A1,"")` in the separate sheet. But a function can only alter the cell it's in, so you'd have to fill it down the column or use a macro to copy a whole column.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a "helper" column to tell us which values to transfer.  In *Sheet1*, cell **D1** enter:

```
=IF(OR(C1="N",C1="R"),1,"")
```

and in **D2** enter:

```
=IF(OR(C2="N",C2="R"),1+MAX($D$1:D1),"")
```

and copy down:

[image]

Then in *Sheet2*, cell **A1** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(ROW(),Sheet1!D:D,0)),"")
```

and copy down:

[image]